# Working with Android camera

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I've started working on video streaming app (from device to pc).
According to what I seen so far, what is better:
1. Using the camera callbacks + encoding to jpeg
2. Using the MediaRecorder (i.e H264 or something else) - I've seen that there are many problems with this API.

tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on the video streaming app and we tried both approaches - note that this was 2-3 years ago.

Option 1. is probably too slow to achieve good rates, we managed around 8-12 fps. Note that this was two years ago and phones were significantly slower.

Option 2. We choose this approach on Androd, it's doable, but there are issues with certain phones.